# How can I choose the number of digits a user can input with an integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I try to run the code, `An error occurred: object of type 'int' has no len()` is what I get back. I am not sure what to do, would appreciate if it there is anyone that could help.

```py
student_id = int(input("Enter Student ID (8-digit number): "))

if len(student_id) != 8:
    print("The student ID number you have entered is invalid, please enter an 8-digit number")

    continue
```

Comment: Convert to string or use value bounds instead of length bounds

Comment: You can do an arithmetic comparison: `if student_id > 99999999:`

Comment: If it's a fixed-length, you probably shouldn't be using a number in the first place, use a string.

Comment: @binaryescape to be pedantic, `int` objects are objects in python.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga good point, i stand corrected; object that is a sequence or collection.

Answer (score 2):

As you have mentioned in the question.

You do not need to convert your `input()` to `int`

```
student_id = int(input("Enter Student ID (8-digit number): "))
```

Just keep it :

```
student_id = input("Enter Student ID (8-digit number): ")
```

By default the data type of `input()` is `string`.

---

```
student_id = input("Enter Student ID (8-digit number): ")
if len(student_id) != 8:
    print("The student ID number you have entered is invalid, please enter an 8-digit number")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if len(str(student_id)) != 8:
    print("The student ID number you have entered is invalid, please enter an 8-digit number")
```

Comment: An even more efficient solution would be to take the input as it is (input() returns string by default). Make the comparison and then convert it to int.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to keep asking the user for an appropriate student ID, you can do it like so:

```py
student_id = int(input("Enter Student ID (8-digit number): "))

while len(str(student_id)) != 8:
    print("The student ID number you have entered is invalid, please enter an 8-digit number")

    student_id = int(input("Enter Student ID (8-digit number): "))
```

Keep in mind however that this code will throw an error if the user passes anything that cannot be used by the `int()` function to the input.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using Regex:

```
while True:
        student_id = int(input("Enter Student ID (8-digit number): "))
        pattern = re.compile("^[0-9]{8}$")
        check_id = pattern.search(str(student_id))
        if check_id:
            print("The student ID number you have entered is valid. Thank you!")
            break
        else:
            print("The student ID number you have entered is invalid, please enter an 8-digit number")
```

Note: just as a reminder your will need to `import re`